# use std::vector for dynamically allocated 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

So I am writing a class, which has 1d-arrays and 2d-arrays, that I dynamically allocate in the constructor

```
class Foo{
int** 2darray;
int * 1darray;
};

Foo::Foo(num1, num2){

2darray = new int*[num1];
for(int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
{     
    array[i] = new int[num2]; 
}
1darray = new int[num1];
}
```

Then I will have to delete every 1d-array and every array in the 2d array in the destructor, right?
I want to use std::vector for not having to do this. Is there any downside of doing this? (makes compilation slower etc?)

TL;DR: when to use std::vector for dynamically allocated arrays, which do NOT need to be resized during runtime?

Comment: IMHO *dynamically allocated arrays* is equal to `std::vector`.  I try to stay as far away from manual memory allocations as I can.

Comment: Always use `std::vector`, unless you really know at compile time how big your array is going to be. Even then, you might want to use a standard container (say a bitset if you want to have a collection of flags). For most use cases, an `std::vector<Type>` that doesn't change size during run-time is the same as a `Type[]`.

Comment: BTW, don't use vector of vectors, use 1D vector for the 2D case too.

Comment: @Ped7g How? I just googled, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Same way as computer memory works. For example the old VGA 320x200 256color mode used memory in segment `A000` from address 0, each 320 bytes representing single row of pixels. So to write `color` at `[x,y]` you had to change memory content at address `y*320 + x`. For a pair indices `[first, second]` you can choose whatever [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) you want, but in computer programming the usual _(second * row_size + first)_ works best (if rows have fixed size).

Comment: @Ped7g Ah, could have thought of this myself, I will consider this. I suppose the reason is simplicity and faster execution?

Comment: Simplicity of source = hard to tell, you are adding the pairing fn, removing additional allocations/management. But compactness in memory = pure win. With `n` * allocating `m` elements you risk of having them at different parts of physical memory, making the job harder for cache. With non trivial access pattern and favourable [n,m] this alone may lead to ten-fold performance difference. Also try to guess which dimension is accessed more often sequentially (cache loves it), and put that one as "column" dimension (creating single row), and the other will jump by row_size (+-1 on row coordinate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector` is fine for the vast majority of uses. Hand-tuned scenarios should first attempt to tune the allocator<sup>1</sup>, and only then modify the container. Correctness of memory management (and your program in general) is worth much, much more than any compilation time gains.

In other words, `vector` should be your starting point, and *until* you find it unsatisfactory, you shouldn't care about anything else.

As an additional improvement, consider using a 1-dimensional `vector` as a backend storage and only provide 2-dimensional indexed view. This scenario can improve the cache locality and overall performance, while also making some operations like copying of the whole structure much easier.

---

<sup>1</sup> the second of two template parameters that `vector` accepts, which defaults to a standard allocator for a given type.

Comment: thanks for the insight. could you explain when to use the allocator ?

Comment: @qeia if you need to ask when, you don't need to customize it.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any drawbacks since [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) guarantees contiguous memory. But if the size is fixed and C++11 is available maybe an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) among other options:

- it doesn't allow resizing
- depending on how the `vector` is initialized prevents reallocations
- size is hardcoded in the instructions (template argument). See Ped7g comment for a more detailed description

Comment: Not a downvoter, just a commenter: "guarantees", not "warranties". Also, please explain your qualified statement about array being a better option.

Comment: @Boris: because with `std::array` the size is hardcoded in instructions (size is template parameter). Which is IMO marginal gain most of the time, and if used by many different sized arrays the code bloat will probably do more damage. But that's just my unqualified assumption (you have to profile the actual code to have any qualified opinion on this :) ). But with 2D arrays (written as 1D) a hardcoded `*rowsize` can be of some advantage, especially with powers of 2 sizes (on modern x86 it very likely will not matter and arbitrary `mul` will be fine).

Comment: @Boris edited to clarify that since there is no need to resize the container an array gets the job done, and prevents misuse. About the wording... ufff close, the only difference I found in the dictionary is that warranties is legal speech and guarantees is not (http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=garantizar)

Comment: No, "warranties" and "guarantees" don't mean the same. Please check an English dictionary, for example Merriam-Webster. Add the content of your earlier comment to your answer.

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, there are reasons, I just felt that these belong to the answer.

Comment: @Boris, edited to include Ped7g comment. Maybe the problem with the wording is that both translate to the same in Spanish....

Answer (score 0):

An 2D array is not a array of pointers.
If you define it this way, each row/colum can have a different size.
Furthermore the elements won't be in sequence in memory.
This might lead to poor performance as the prefetcher wont be able to predict your access-patterns really well.
Therefore it is not advised to nest std::vectors inside eachother to model multi-dimensional arrays.
A better approach is to map an continuous chunk of memory onto an mult-dimensional space by providing custom access methods.

You can test it in the browser: http://fiddle.jyt.io/github/3389bf64cc6bd7c2218c1c96f62fa203

```
#include<vector>

template<class T>
struct Matrix {
  Matrix(std::size_t n=1, std::size_t m=1)
    : n{n}, m{m}, data(n*m)
  {}

  Matrix(std::size_t n, std::size_t m, std::vector<T> const& data)
    : n{n}, m{m}, data{data}
  {}

  //Matrix M(2,2, {1,1,1,1});

  T const&  operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
    return data[i*m + j];
  }

  T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    return data[i*m + j];
  }

  size_t n;
  size_t m;
  std::vector<T> data;
  using ScalarType = T;
};
```

You can implement operator[] by returning a VectorView which has access to data an index and the dimensions.